# Why I can't change object material/color?

Tags: materials

I don't understand why I can't add a new material to the object. I can change the colour on the right, but not in the shader editor. My file: https://workupload.com/file/y4rt8bJrY4z [image]

Comment: Hello could you please share the plane object?

Comment: Don't know yet how to share only the object but added the whole file!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You disabled *Use nodes* inside the *Shader Editor* (top bar). Just enable it.

Comment: Okay, but when I enable them, the material turns black and nothing happens. Also, noticed that BSDF is gone on other materials

Comment: You need to create an Output > Material Output and plug the Principled BSDF into it

Comment: Please mark my answer as resolved. For other people and for my personnal dopamin.